# Google calendar API does not work as .exe

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, exe

I have a python program that utilises the Google calendar API. When running it in the IDE, it works completely fine. However, when converted to an executable file (.exe) the whole program will not run due to it. I tried creating the executable via auto-py-to-exe, pyinstaller and cx-freeze but no luck. When running the executable file, I get the error "failed to execute script".

```
    #for google calendar API
    import pickle
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import pytz
    import os.path
    from apiclient.discovery import build
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
    import datefinder
    
    #for pyinstaller to create .exe file properly
    import sys, os 
    def resource_path(relative_path):
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
        return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
    
    credentials = pickle.load(open(resource_path('credentials.pkl'), "rb"))
    service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)
    #getting all calendars
    result = service.calendarList().list().execute()
    #getting main calendar events
    calendar_id = result['items'][0]['id']
```

Comment: Can you reduce the program down to a minimal failing example? It's possible but unlikely, for example, that the google calendar api is relevant. There are a number of debugging steps for pyinstaller on https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html . Which did you try already, and what were the results?

Comment: Thank you for your input @PaulHankin! I tried using --debug, but could not figure out the error using it. However, I can tell you that when I comment out the lines which build the calendar (as you can see on my code), creating an exe file becomes possible. Obviously, the program does not run well in that case as part of it is commented out, but at least I am quite certain that it is the api that causes the trouble.